# setStiffnesses on Pepper to move arms

Tags: pepper

I would like to put Pepper in a specific position (a little bit like when using the strike a pose application. I use this minimal code :

```
import qi

session = qi.Session()
session.connect("tcp://YOUR_IP:9559")
almotion = session.service("ALMotion")
almotion.setStiffnesses("RArm", 0.0)
```

1. I run the piece of code above (the right arm be be moved now)
2. I hold the right arm in the position I want
3. I run the same code above with stiffness of 1.0

However, this does not fix the arm in the position I was holding. The arm goes down, and then the stiffness is set to 1.0.

When I do the same with "Head" instead of "RArm", this works fine, as if the motors would not fix when we hold them. How should I do?

EDIT 1: After disabling autonomous abilities, I still get the issue that the arms are not blocking in the position I am holding. My code is currently:

```
import sys
import qi

stiffness = 1.0
if len(sys.argv) > 1: stiffness = float(sys.argv[1])

session = qi.Session()
session.connect("tcp://YOUR_IP:9559")

almotion = session.service("ALMotion")
almotion.setBreathEnabled("Body", False) # Also tried True
almotion.setIdlePostureEnabled("Body", False) # Also tried True

allife = session.service("ALAutonomousLife")
allife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("BackgroundMovement", False)
allife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("BasicAwareness", False)
allife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("ListeningMovement", False)
allife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("SpeakingMovement", False)

almotion.stiffnessInterpolation("LArm", stiffness, 1.0)
```

Test it with

```
python code.py 0.0 # To free the left arm
# Move the left arm how you wish
python code.py 1.0 # To fix the arm
```

Answer (score 0):

There are "[autonomous abilities](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/ref/life/autonomous_abilities_management.html#autonomous-abilities-management)" on Pepper that are making it breath, look around, and taking the arms down. You want to have those disabled in your case.

To do so, add to your code:

```
alife = session.service("ALAutonomousLife")
alife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("BackgroundMovement", False)
alife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("BasicAwareness", False)
alife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("ListeningMovement", False)
alife.setAutonomousAbilityEnabled("SpeakingMovement", False)
```

You can also do it with `ALMotion.setIdlePostureEnabled` & `ALMotion.setBreathEnabled`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same issue. See "Edit 1".

Comment: Is it the same with ALMotion.setIdlePostureEnabled & ALMotion.setBreathEnabled?

Answer (score 0):

NAO and Pepper robots regulate the stiffness of their joints automatically to reduce over-heating and energy consumption. See [this documentation page](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/reflexes-smart-stiffness.html).
I think you can trust it to provide you a safe stiffness value for you to move the joints of the robot.

In my experience, if you gently force Pepper's arm, the stiffness will automatically reduce until you can move the arm. Then if you let the arm still and stop forcing it, the stiffness will automatically come back.

However, if this is not satisfactory and want to control the stiffness, you may disable the smart stiffness using `almotion.setSmartStiffnessEnabled(False)`.

Then don't forget that your call to `almotion.stiffnessInterpolation("LArm", stiffness, 1.0)` will take 1.0 second to turn the stiffness on, and that this is enough time for the arm to fall. Make sure that the trigger to turn the stiffness on occurs some time before the user drops the Pepper's arm.